# Count the number of Salt minions matched

Tags: saltstack

Is there a simple way to count the number of minions returned by a match, for example:

```
salt -C 'G@ec2_roles:test' match.count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `--summary` to any salt call like:

```
salt -C 'G@ec2_roles:test' --summary
```

The you will get an report at the end of the execution which tells you how many minions were targeted:

```
-------------------------------------------
Summary
-------------------------------------------
# of minions targeted: 528
# of minions returned: 501
# of minions that did not return: 27
# of minions with errors: 0
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Didn't know about this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the output format and run it through wc:

```
salt -C 'G@ec2_roles:test' test.ping --out=txt | wc -l
```